# Replacing part of a string in pandas column with `and` condition

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a `pandas dataframe` that looks like this:

```
    Size    Measure     Location    Messages
    Small     1         Washington  TXT0123 TXT0875 TXT874 TXT0867 TXT0875 TXT0874
    Medium    2         California  TXT020 TXT017 TXT120 TXT012
    Large     3         Texas       TXT0123 TXT0123 TXT0123 TXT0123 TXT0217 TXT0206
    Small     4         California  TXT020 TXT0217 TXT006
    Tiny      5         Nevada      TXT0206 TXT0217 TXT0206
```

I am trying to remove the 0 from the individual words in the `Messages` column if the length equals 7 and the fourth character is 0.

I've tried for loop, but it's removing all 0's:

```
for line in df.Messages:
    for message in line.split():
        if len(message) == 7 and message[3] == '0':
            print(message.replace('0', ''))
```

I also tried `.map` which gave me some errors:

```
df.Messages = df.Messages.map(lambda x: x.replace('0', '') for message in line.split() for line in df.Messages if (len(message) == 7 and message[3] == '0'))

TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to do this with `.map` that includes the `if` and `and` conditionals?

Comment: You wish to apply this condition to _each_ word? Or to the whole string?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sorry, to each individual word. Updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you want to do this for each word, first split your column with `str.split`, call `apply`, and then re-join with `str.join`:

```
def f(l):
    return [w.replace('0', '') if len(w) == 7 and w[3] == '0' else w for w in l]

df.Messages.str.split().apply(f).str.join(' ')

0    TXT123 TXT875 TXT874 TXT867 TXT875 TXT874
1                  TXT020 TXT017 TXT120 TXT012
2     TXT123 TXT123 TXT123 TXT123 TXT217 TXT26
3                         TXT020 TXT217 TXT006
4                           TXT26 TXT217 TXT26
Name: Messages, dtype: object
```

If you want to replace just the single 0 (and not all of them), use `w.replace('0', '', 1)` in function `f` instead.

Comment: should  TXT0206 still to be TX206?

Comment: @Wen Hmm... good question... not sure about that. You can just use `str.replace(..., 1)` otherwise.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for this! I did just want the single 0, though I didn't realize that until TXT0206 was mentioned... Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
df.Messages.str.split().apply(pd.Series).fillna('').\
    applymap(lambda x : x[:2]+x[4:] if len(x)==7 and x[3]=='0' else x).\ 
       apply(' '.join,1)
```

Out[597]:

```
0    TX123 TX875 TXT874 TX867 TX875 TX874
1           TXT020 TXT017 TXT120 TXT012  
2     TX123 TX123 TX123 TX123 TX217 TX206
3                  TXT020 TX217 TXT006   
4                    TX206 TX217 TX206   
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
In [17]: df['Messages'] = df['Messages'].str.replace(r'(\D+)0(\d{3})',r'\1\2')

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
     Size  Measure    Location                                   Messages
0   Small        1  Washington  TXT123 TXT875 TXT874 TXT867 TXT875 TXT874
1  Medium        2  California                TXT020 TXT017 TXT120 TXT012
2   Large        3       Texas  TXT123 TXT123 TXT123 TXT123 TXT217 TXT206
3   Small        4  California                       TXT020 TXT217 TXT006
4    Tiny        5      Nevada                       TXT206 TXT217 TXT206
```